# More than they had before

Tags: grammar, past-tense

As for history-present times comparison. Let's say Japan's earthquake is more frequent than in the past, can you say:

> Japan has more earthquakes today than they *had* **before**.

Or

> Japan has more earthquakes today than they *had* **in the past**.

Which is more correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, both are correct statements. As a native speaker, the second statement sounds slightly more formal but they both convey the same meaning overall.